# Is there convection between two volumes of air at different temperatures?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow, convection, heat-conduction

As I have learned in my engineering classes convection takes place when a fluid meets a surface of both different temperatures. My question: can this also be evaluated for two volumes of air at different temperatures separated by a door for example?. What happens when the door opens and which convection type would be dominant in the case if there is a forced flow on one side of the door?

Is it possible to calculate values for the Archimedes number, Grashof number and Reynolds number?

I hope someone can explain how I would evaluate such a situation. Thank you in advance!

-Jesse

Comment: What is your understanding of the fundamental mechanism for convective heat transfer (hint, it is not simply that a fluid and a surface have different temperatures).

Comment: @ChetMiller I just started my course in heat transfer and fluid mechanics. They explained the basics of convection, conduction etc along with the relevant equations. I'm a second year Bsc mechanical engineer in university. I know that heat transfer can be calculated in terms of its heat transfer coefficient, area and temperature difference. Also I've seen that the heat transfer coefficient is dependend on Reynolds numbers and therefore flow velocities. That is basically where my knowledge ends.

Comment: What convection does is produce shear flow parallel to the boundary which causes the thickness of the thermal boundary layer at the surface to become thinner, and thereby increase the temperature gradient across the boundary layer and the corresponding rate of conductive heat transfer through the boundary layer.  Do you know how to reduce the partial differential equations for flow and energy transfer to dimensionless form?  This automatically elucidates the key dimensionless groups.

Comment: @ChetMiller Oh okay. I do not know how to reduce the partial differential equations I think. Especially not for two volumes of different flows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For volumes of air of different temperatures separated by a vertical opening such as a doorway, the physics is different to that of convective flow over a heated surface.

If we have two volumes of air at different temperatures separated by a vertical opening, the interface in the plane of the opening is not stable and a flow will result. The flow is driven by the difference in hydrostatic pressure between the two sides of the opening and is structured, with the warmer, lighter air occupying the top portion of the opening and the cooler, denser air occupying the bottom portion. For a rectangular opening of width $W$ and height $H$ separating rooms with air of density $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2>\rho_1$, the flow rate $Q_{ex}$ can be shown ([Epstein 1989](https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/heattransfer/article-abstract/111/4/980/382945/Combined-Natural-Convection-and-Forced-Flow?redirectedFrom=fulltext)) to be

$$
Q_{ex}=\frac{C_D}{3}WH^{3/2}g'^{1/2},
$$

where

$$
g'=\frac{\rho_2-\rho_1}{\bar{\rho}}
$$

is the reduced gravity, $\bar{\rho}$ is the average density and $C_D=O(1)$ is a loss coefficient for the opening.

The analysis of Epstein (1989) actually considered the case when there is a forced flow through the door, the result above being a limiting value of no forcing. As the forcing is increased, initially there is still flow in both directions, though now the exchange volume flow against the forcing is less than that with the forcing. When the forcing reaches a critical value, sometimes called the flooding rate, there is no longer an exchange and the flow through the opening becomes unidirectional. Epstein (1989) calculated the flooding rate $Q_F$ to be

$$
Q_F=2^{3/2}Q_{ex}.
$$

Let me know if you would like any more information.